# Query regarding integer in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

Can we put integer in my xpath query like "A/B/123". If No then can you please tell me is there any way to put integers in xpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first character of XML element names is restricted to the following set

> `":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]`

See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar. This does not include digits.

Why not use an attribute in your markup and search for that in your XPath query, eg

#### XML

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C id="123" />
    </B>
</A>
```

#### XPath

```
A/B/C[@id="123"]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can we put integer in my xpath query like "A/B/123".

**The answer is negative**, because in the location step `/123` the string `123` is neither a node-test or a node name.

**A simple rule to remember** is that in XML a name must start with a letter (or an underscore) and the rest of the characters can be either letters, underscores or numbers. The letters aren't restricted to belong only to the Latin alphabet (could be from the Greek, or Cyrillic, or ... alphabet)

**So, the following are all syntactically correct**:

```
/A/B/C123

/A/B/C_123

/A/B/_123

/π/Σ/φ_123

/А/Б/Щ_123

/A/B/C[. = 123]    

/A/B/C[. = '123']

/A/B/C[text() = 123]    

/A/B/C[text() = '123']    

/A/B/C[@someAttribName = 123]

/A/B/C[@someAttribName = '123']
```

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 2.0 the expression X/Y/123 is legal, but it doesn't do anything very useful: it returns a sequence consisting of as many instances of 123 as there are elements in X/Y.

As others have responded: what are you trying to achieve?